# Proper mapping for service architectures, Docker and BitBucket mapping - how do you do it?

Tags: bitbucket, methodology

With Atlassian BitBucket, you can have:

- Projects, which incorporate..
- Source code repositories.

Now, you could have a microservices with more than just one codebase and need therefore more than just repository. What is the best practice to reflect this if you have many different projects?

My idea now is to encode microservice prefixes to repository names, but is this really the way to go?

Like:

- Project A

  - service1.repo1
  - service1.repo2
  - service2.repo1
- Project B

  - serviceN.repoX

Comment: Can you give concrete examples?

Comment: They are given above

Answer (score 1):

One could also create libraries and call them using a dependency manager like a package.json if node is used or ivy if the code is written in java.

Comment: But what does this mean to repo layout?